# Enabling cloth physics for an object moves its transform position

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aes92iyzFWA&t) about how to model and animate a scroll, and I've only deviated from the steps by decreasing the number of cuts when subdividing the "paper" and decreasing the vertices on the "handle", in order to make it low-poly (I also have followed the tutorial without these changes and also have had the same problem).

Whenever I apply the cloth physics modifier, however, the paper of the scroll acts weirdly. The only way I can describe it is that the paper doesn't stick to the handle and instead, it deforms, and its transform position decreases significantly in the Z-axis.

Below is what I see before the cloth modifier was applied:

[image: With no cloth physics applied]

And this is what I see after the modifier has been applied:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same or a similar issue right now, though I know I'm late.
I wasn't at frame 1 so the cloth simulation had basically ended - my object had already "fallen" and was therefore further down the z-axis. Going back to frame 1 solved it. If you weren't able to solve the problem, maybe this will help you too or anyone else encountering this.

Comment: You save my life! Although one can solve this by randomly clicking things, but your instruction surely gives a reasonable answer.